# Does Exact Target block tracking on certain domains

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion

A sandbox environment has a conversion tracking `<img>` tag which reports back correctly to exact target. When releasing this codebase to a pre-production instance with the same build number but with development in the URL, the tracking no longer functions even though the '' tag is present and populated correctly ([according to the documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/conversion_tracking/)) in the DOM tree.

I understand exact target blocks subscribers with domains such as @admin, @marketing, @test, etc and wondering if there is any rules around disabling conversion tracking on certain domains?  Can't seem to find any documentation on the matter.

Testing in pre production environment (with development in URL) is from same Business Unit, just a link changed to new URL for tracking purposes.